# Intermediate layer outputs pytorch

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I have Alexnet neural network:

```
class AlexNet(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, num_classes=100):
    super(AlexNet, self).__init__()
    self.features = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=11, stride=4, padding=2),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
        nn.Conv2d(64, 192, kernel_size=5, padding=2),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
        nn.Conv2d(192, 384, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(384, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
    )
    self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Dropout(),
        nn.Linear(256 * 6 * 6, 4096),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Dropout(),
        nn.Linear(4096, 4096),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Linear(4096, num_classes),
    )

def forward(self, x):
    x = self.features(x)
    x = x.view(x.size(0), 256 * 6 * 6)
    x = self.classifier(x)
    return x
```

I am trying to get the information of the intermediate layers (for example the penultimate layer ) with backward hook but I couldn't get it

Answer (score 1):

According to this [answer](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/inference-on-specific-layers-of-a-model/98313/2)

You have to split your model in different parts and create methods to access them parts such as :

```
class AlexNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes=100):
        super(AlexNet, self).__init__()
        self.features = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=11, stride=4, padding=2),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 192, kernel_size=5, padding=2),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
            nn.Conv2d(192, 384, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(384, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=3, padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2),
        )
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Dropout(),
            nn.Linear(256 * 6 * 6, 4096),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Dropout(),
            nn.Linear(4096, 4096),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Linear(4096, num_classes),
        )

    def getFeatures(self,x):
        x = self.features(x)
        return x.view(x.size(0), 256 * 6 * 6)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.features(x)
        x = x.view(x.size(0), 256 * 6 * 6)
        x = self.classifier(x)
        return x
```

This way is quite common and you can find [plenty of examples](https://github.com/lukemelas/EfficientNet-PyTorch/blob/master/efficientnet_pytorch/model.py#L278).